# React.js and Node.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, heroku, buildpack

I've created a react app with node.js and stored it on github.

I've tried to deploy it to Heroku, but it has kept giving me an error.

"App not compatible with buildpack:"

My repo folder has two files "api" and "client".
Each folder has package.json inside.
I feel like the buildpack path should lead package.json file directly.

How can I launch my react website through github?

Answer (score 0):

To launch your React app, you need to deploy your frontend app and backend app separately. Unfortunately, Heroku won't recognize a combined repo with both folders.

An easier way is to create two separate GitHub repos for your api subfolder and client subfolder. Use **React buildpack** for the frondend app and **NodeJS buildpack** for the backend app.

Alternative solution is to manually deploy your apps through `git subtree push`, for which you can refer to [this tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deploy-multiple-apps-under-a-single-github-repository-to-heroku-f6177489d38).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, buildpack should be `heroku/nodejs` on heroku setting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).